# How can I recursively check if nested subclasses have each other as parent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I know my question is somewhat confusing, but I'll try my best to make myself clear. Here's a sample code I've made to try to illustrate the problem:

```
class X:

  def __init__(self, p=None):
    self.parent = p

class Y(X):

  def __init__(self, p=None):
    X.__init__(self, p)

  def recursive_check(self):
    if (self.parent.parent.parent):
      print(self.parent.parent.parent)

x0 = X()
x1 = X(x0)
x2 = X(x1)
y = Y(x2)
y.recursive_check()
```

As you can see, if you try to access `self.parent.parent.parent.parent` you'll get a None. The problem is that I don't know how nested the parents can be, so I can't directly test if they exist like that. I want to check recursively the depth of the nest, it could have 100 instances nesting on each other. For the sake of this example, I just need to print each parent address if it exists.

EDIT:

Considering the accepted answer, that's how I've achieved what I wanted:

```
class X:

  def __init__(self, p=None):
    self.parent = p

  def recursive_check(self):
    if self.parent:
        print(self.parent)
        self.parent.recursive_check()

class Y(X):

  def __init__(self, p=None):
    X.__init__(self, p)

x0 = X()
x1 = X(x0)
x2 = X(x1)
y = Y(x2)
y.recursive_check()
```

OBS: I'm developing a GUI for Pygame and this has to do with nested Panels (Layout Management). I don't know how nested the panels can be.

Comment: What exactly are you checking for? The earliest ancestor?

Comment: The last, actually. I want to check from top to bottom, if each one exists, and stop when it ends on None.

Comment: The thing is that "y" could have N number of parents. I don't know how many, it depends on the user. If y have 1000 parents, I'd need to access all of them, checking if they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the memory address printing:

```
def recursive_check(self):
    if self.parent:
        print(id(self.parent))
        self.parent.recursive_check()
```

If your ancestry can have circles, you'd have to collect each parent and pass that set on down the recursive calls to avoid infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a loop, which avoids runtime errors when the stack of parents gets too large.

```
def recursive_check(self):
    top = self
    p = self.parent
    while p is not None:
        top = p
        p = top.parent
    print(top)
```

Comment: Non-recursive is definitely the better appraoch. Actually you don't need the `p`: `while top.parent is not None: top = top.parent` saves you two lines.